# Interlock compareexchange for collection

Tags: c#, lock-free

I am using a concurrentqueue so multiple users can write their information in. At the background, I am using a timer to save down whatever in the queue to the database on a time basis. My code is as blow:

```
public void WriteInformation(sting msg)
{
    ConcurrentQueue<MessageQueueItem> oldQueue;
        do
        {
            oldQueue = messageQueue;
            messageQueue.Enqueue(msg);
        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref oldQueue, null, messageQueue) != null);
}
```

In my timer's elapse method, I am recreating the concurrent queue and process the old queue, as below:

```
var oldQueue = Volatile.Read(ref messageQueue);
Volatile.Write(ref messageQueue, new ConcurrentQueue<string>());

// process the old queue;
string item;
if (oldQueue.TryDequeue(out item))
{
    // compact item and save to DB.
}
```

Is this pattern correct? Also I don't think

```
var oldQueue = Volatile.Read(ref messageQueue);
Volatile.Write(ref messageQueue, new ConcurrentQueue<string>());
```

is necessary. I can use code below instead as in my WriteInformation method, I am already checking if messageQueue is the up-to-date copy. Is it correct? WriteInformation and messageQueue are static. Thanks.

```
var oldQueue = messageQueue;
messageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry about the volatility of a singleton reference. Just access it via a static field, or via dependency injection, after it's correctly initialized. What other threads change is the data in the queue, not the reference of the queue. The reference should never be modified after initialization.

Comment: the DB action is quite slow, that is why I want to create a new queue for people to input data and my timer thread can process the old queue in the background.

Comment: @Helic what particular problem does the second queue solve? Why cannot you consume from the same queue that is being enqueued?

Comment: @zerkms, i think too frequent calls to the WriteInformation method will lock the collection too many times and delay the DB action, and vice versa

Comment: @Helic the first performance optimisation rule: measure and prove scientifically that something is slow and needs optimisation.

Comment: @zerkms, yes, it may not be necessary to do it in this way. But do I need to use Volatile read and write when assigning a new collection in this case?

Comment: I would say yes (and even more - there is a chance that even your code might be not good enough on some cpu architectures: you need a (release) memory barrier *between* a fully constructed object and its assignment. From what I see on MSDN - `Volatile.Write` does not guarantee that), but the memory barriers and lock-free subjects are extremely complicated, and unless you fully understand the implications, which include the memory model, the compiler optimisations and the cpu specific optimisations - I would avoid it.